# What is the numerical basis for a string to be alphabetically sorted?

Tags: sorting

If I have the names, "johnny" and "bobby," how can I use the computer to sort those?

If I compare them to each other numerically it doesn't seem to hold for all conditions.

Consider:

```
def listsum(numList):
    theSum = 0
    for i in numList:
        theSum = theSum + i
    return theSum

test = 0
mystr='BA'
for code in map(ord, mystr):
    test = test + listsum([code])
    print(test)
```

131

and then change,

```
mystr='AZ'
```

get 155.

So, I can't just do an ASCII comparison.  So what do I use for a basis if I do it manually?  I do not want to use any particular language or any built in sort methods.

Comment: You did not tage your language, but it looks like Python or Ruby.  In any case, you would need to compare each letter lexigraphically for two strings.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I did not tag the language because I do not want it based upon any particular language.  I'm interested in the concept and used Python for an example.

Answer (score 2):

Compare the first character. If one of them is earlier than the other in the encoding order, then the string is earlier than the other - and vice versa. If they are the same, proceed to the next character and do the same. If you reach the end of both strings, the strings are equal. If you reach the end of one string, that string is earlier.

Summing has nothing to do with lexicographical ordering.

As an example, here's a clear, but not really optimal, implementation of the above:

```
def str_cmp(a, b):
    la = len(a)
    lb = len(b)

    if la == 0 and lb == 0:
        return 0    # two empty strings are equal
    if la == 0:
        return -1   # an empty string is earlier than a non-empty one
    if lb == 0:
        return 1    # a non-empty string is later than an empty one

    oa = ord(a[0])
    ob = ord(b[0])

    if oa < ob:
        return -1   # a string whose initial character is earlier is earlier
    if oa > ob:
        return 1    # a string whose initial character is later is later

    return str_cmp(a[1:], b[1:])   # strings with same initial characters compare
                                   # the same as the strings with those characters
                                   # chopped off
```

You can use this function as a `cmp` parameter to `sort` or `sorted`, if you wish.